# Removing surplus characters in a Phone Number column in Marketing Cloud using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

In Marketing Cloud, we receive phone numbers from our CRM in a following format: +3xx yyyyzzzz or 003xx yyyyzzzz. We would need to remove the extra '+' or '00' as well as the extra spacing inserted between '+3xx' and 'yyyyzzzz' to avoid any errors occurring when sending text messages. We need to do it during audience creation, i.e. using the SQL in Automation Studio.
Obviously, we will need a CASE statements to achieve this, but would be the best function here, SUBSTRING? If yes, I have trouble connecting the first part (extra values of + or 00) and the empty spacing in the middle. Please see the code:

Example code:

```
    SELECT Name, 
    LastName, 
    CASE WHEN (SUBSTRING(Phone_Number,1,1) LIKE '+' OR SUBSTRING(Phone_Number,1,2) LIKE 00) 
AND (SUBSTRING(Phone_number, 4,1) LIKE ' ' OR SUBSTRING(Phone_Number,5,1) LIKE ' ') 
THEN...//What next?
    FROM Customers
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that in each of the phone numbers, what you are looking for is prepending the part you want to keep, the following should work:

1. Replace all spaces inside of string via REPLACE()
2. Cut off all 'extra' characters from the left side of the string via RIGHT()

This should then leave you with your phone number without the unnecessary prepends or the spaces.  You can manipulate this even more if you need to replace other chars as well (e.g. parenthesis, dashes, etc.).

```
SELECT ...,
RIGHT(REPLACE(phone_column,' ',''),10) as PhoneNumber 
FROM [myDE]
```

This would take the value of `'+3 111 222 3333'` and output it as `1112223333`.

By just pushing more REPLACE()s around the `phone_column` you can remove other special chars.

e.g. **Parenthesis**

```
RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone_column,' ',''),'(',''),'(',''),10) as PhoneNumber
/* Removes parenthesis from phone number */
```

e.g. **Dashes**

```
RIGHT(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone_column,' ',''),'-',''),10) as PhoneNumber
/* Removes dashes from phone number */
```

I chose the number 10 for RIGHT() to fit with the US phone numbers, this can change depending on your location, etc.

Comment: OK, I like your solution as opposed to SUBSTRING (both should work I reckon).